# F# Continuation Passing FoldBack

Tags: f#

I am struggling with understanding foldback with CPS.
This one I can understand:

```
let listFoldBack combine acc l =
  let rec Loop l cont =
    match l with
    | h :: t -> Loop t (fun racc -> cont (combine h racc))
    | [] -> cont acc
  Loop l id     

listFoldBack   (fun x a  -> (2*x::a) ) [] [1;2;3]

// call sequence
[1;2;3]    id
Loop [2;3] (fun a -> (combine 1 a))
Loop [3]   (fun a -> (combine 1 (combine 2 a)))
Loop []    (fun a -> (combine 1 (combine 2 (combine 3 a))))
           (fun a -> (combine 1 (combine 2 (combine 3 a)))) []
           2::(4::(6::[]))
```

---

But then:

```
let  fib n =
  let rec fibc a cont =
    if a <= 2 then cont 1
    else      
      fibc (a - 2) (fun x -> fibc (a - 1) (fun y -> cont(x + y)))      
  fibc n id

// call sequence
fibc (4) id
 fibc (2) (fun x -> fibc (3) (fun y -> id(x + y)))
   (fun x -> fibc (3) (fun y -> id(x + y))) (1) 
     fibc (3) (fun y -> id(1 + y))
       fibc (1) (fun x -> fibc (2) (fun y -> (fun z -> id(1+z)) (x + y)))
          fibc (2) (fun y -> (fun z -> id(1+z))(1 + y)))
            (fun y -> (fun z -> id(1+z))(1 + y))) (1)
               fun z -> id(1+z)(1+1)
                 id (1+2)
                   3
```

Very difficult to follow.

---

Even worse:

```
type Tree<'a> =
    | Leaf
    | Node of 'a * Tree<'a> * Tree<'a>

let node x l r = Node(x,l,r)

let treeFoldBack f leaf tree =
    let rec loop t cont = 
        match t with 
        | Leaf -> cont leaf
        | Node(x,l,r) -> loop l (fun lacc -> 
            loop r (fun racc -> cont(f x lacc racc))) 
    loop tree id

let tree1 =
    (node 4
        (node 2
            (node 1 Leaf Leaf)
            (node 3 Leaf Leaf))
        (node 6
            (node 5 Leaf Leaf)
            (node 7 Leaf Leaf)))

    // call sequence by means of text replacing 
        ... a lot of steps, lines too long to fit
        cont(f 4 (f 2 (f 1 Leaf Leaf) (f 3 Leaf Leaf)) 
        (f 6 (f 5 Leaf Leaf) (f 7 Leaf Leaf))))
```

The result is correct, but very difficult to follow.
For all cases the pattern is like:

```
loop l (fun lacc -> loop r (fun racc -> cont(f x lacc racc))) 
calculate loop l, result goes in lacc.
calculate loop r, result goes in racc.
calculate f x lacc racc and result is argument for cont.
```

Why does this work? how to understand this?

Answer (score 13):

I think that the best way to understand continuation passing style is to compare the ordinary non-continuation version of a function with the continuation-based function. Using your "even worse" example of tree fold, let's write the function using ordinary recursion first:

```
let treeFoldBack f leaf tree =
    let rec loop t = 
        match t with 
        | Leaf -> leaf
        | Node(x,l,r) -> 
            let lacc = loop l // Process left and return result
            let racc = loop r // Process right and return result
            f x lacc racc     // Aggregate current, left and right
    loop tree
```

As you can see, the function is not tail-recursive in the `Node` case, because we call `loop`, then call `loop` again and then finally call `f`.

The idea of continuations is to add a parameter that represents "what to do after the current operation has completed". This is captured by `cont`. In case of `Leaf`, we just replace returning `leaf` with calling continuation with `leaf` as an argument. The `Node` case is more elaborate:

```
let treeFoldBack f leaf tree =
    let rec loop t cont = 
        match t with 
        | Leaf -> cont leaf
        | Node(x,l,r) -> 
            loop l (fun lacc -> // Process left and continue with result
              loop r (fun racc -> // Process right and continue with result
                cont(f x lacc racc))) // Aggregate and invoke final continuation
    loop tree id
```

As you can see, the structure is the same as before - but rather than calling `loop` and storing the result using `let`, we now call `loop` and pass it a *function* that gets the result and does the rest of the work.

This looks a bit confusing until you get used to it - but the key thing is that this is actually a fairly mechanical translation - you just replace `let` with `fun` in the right way!

Comment: I was reviewing this question and saw I forgot to say thanks for your excellent explanation, it really helped. Thanks!